# Telerik MVC Tree. Force data update from the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have a Treeview bound to the Model. Can I force from the client to reload all the data and re-render the TreeView?

Comment: There is a treeview with .BindTo(Model.ListOFFoo... and a button, when I click the button TreeView should be reloaded... I can do that with PartialViews, but I'm curious if it's possible to re-render TreeView directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add AJAX binding to your TreeView, you can rebind & re-render it by calling the `ajaxRequest` client-side method, like `$("#TreeView").data("tTreeView").ajaxRequest();`

Comment: but it has to be ajax binding right? I can't just bind it to the model

Comment: It's getting a bit complicated when you have a few levels of hierarchy

Comment: yes, it has to have ajax binding in order to work. it also enables you to use the `ajaxRequest(item)` that updates a subtree.